# Symfony form large data set

Tags: php, forms, symfony, symfony4

For a Symfony 4 project we need to make a large `inpection` form about `surfaces` with many fields. We're looking for the approach how to organize the structure and relationships and keep load speed in mind.

I've created the basic entity example below, which is still simple to be stored in one database table. The fields below are simple relations or string fields so a InspectionType would be easy.

```
class Inspection
{
    /** @var string */
    protected $projectName;

    /** @var string */
    protected $projectPlace;

    /** @var User */
    protected $inpector;

    /** @var Customer */
    protected $customer;

    /** @var string */
    protected $conclusion;

    /** @var string */
    protected $advice;

    // Complex part
    
    /** @var Collection */
    protected $surfaces;
}
```

Now for the complex part.
Each inspection could contain one or more surfaces (ArrayCollection).
Each surface consists of different fields, see below:

- **Roof surface** (4 fields);

1. text type
2. choice type (single)
3. choice type (multiple)
4. date type

- **Leakage** (3 fields);

1. text type
2. images (relation, OneToMany)
3. choice type (single)

- **Tension** (3 fields);
- **Slope** (3 fields);
- **Roof Pollution** (3 fields);
- **Damage** (5 fields);
- **Ballast** (3 fields);
- **Eaves** (3 fields);
- **UprightWork** (4 fields);
- **Dilation Rebellion** (5 fields);
- **Chimney** (3 fields);
- **Shunt Box** (3 fields);
- ... 9 more+;

My question how to setup `surfaces` and database structure, should each part in a surface have its on table like below with a relation back to inspection (this would create many tables, is this bad?):

- table inpection
- table inpection_leakage
- table inpection_tension
- ...

I was thinking to create an Embed Collection Form like below

```
class InspectionType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        // ...

        $builder->add('surfaces', CollectionType::class, [
            'entry_type' => SurfaceType::class,
            'entry_options' => ['label' => false],
        ]);
    }
}

class SurfaceType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('leakage', LeakageTyoe::class);
        $builder->add('tension', Tension::class);
        $builder->add('slope', Slope::class);
        ...
    }
}
```

Is this the way :) to go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to use a [discriminator/inheritance map](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#single-table-inheritance) for your surfaces entity, with a `single_table` strategy. This gives you the speed and flexibility you need.

Comment: Does this method not create many columns when some childs has their own fields. Because each single table (Leakage, Tension) does not have all the same field, see updated above in code

Comment: Could Class Table Inheritance, https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#class-table-inheritance be an option

Comment: Single table does indeed create more columns, but that is okay. When loading your `Leakage` entity, it will only use the fields it needs for Leakage, and the same for Tension. Class Table Inheritance is indeed also an option. It basically does the same thing as single table inheritance. However, be cautious that when you have many records, you might experience slower performance. Thats why I suggested single_table strategy.

Comment: Does Table Inheritance create a table per surface (`leakage`, `tension`). And what about same fields (inheritance). Should i only put these fields to its parent and child specific in the childs only? I tend to Class table inheritance because it describes like: This mapping strategy provides the greatest flexibility at design time, since changes to any type are always limited to that type's dedicated table. Is it possible to switch later on?. And how about images. This is a new relation so a new table?

Comment: Yes, Class Table Inheritance (CTI) creates a table for each surface. With single table, overlapping fields should be placed in the parent, with CTI you place it in its own class. Just try them both out and see what works best for you. As for switching to single table at a later time: Yes this is possible. However, you will need to manually write migrations to do so. If you want to add Images, i suppose you need a new entity, thus a new table will be created. Relating it to your surfaces should not be a problem.

Comment: Update to previous answer with a new question. Each surface has a collection of images (ContextImages). How does this relation work. How do i now which surface belongs to which contextImage. Should each surface gets is own table, leakage_context, tension_context.

Comment: I think you should ask, which images are related to which Surface. I assume that each Surface can have multiple ContextImages, and that each ContextImage can only have _one_ Surface. Thus, you need a one to many relation. [check it here](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-bidirectional). Note that doctrine will create the tables for you automatically when you update your schemas (e.g. with migrations or schema update).

Comment: And what about Symfony forms with CTI. Started new question, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64975018/symfony-form-with-doctrine-class-table-inheritance-cti