# Symfony Form with Doctrine Class Table Inheritance (CTI)

Tags: forms, symfony, inheritance, doctrine-orm, symfony4

In a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64765531/symfony-form-large-data-set) I ask how to handle large forms, outcome was Single Table Inheritance (STI) or CTI, [Inheritance mapping](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/inheritance-mapping.html). I've has chosen for CTI.

Now i'm dealing how to create the form with CTI. A quick overview what kind or relation there are.

Each `inspection` could have one or more `surfaces`. Each surface consists of many sub entities, like: `surface_leakage`, `surface_tension` or `surface_slope`. As you could see `surface` has the CTI with sub entities. Some fields overlap (put them in parent), some don't (put them in child). But in the end I need one form with all the fields grouped by surfaces then by child (maybe Bootrap collapse).

Setting up the relation was not that hard, but to use it into a form is difficult and I'm not sure how I could handle this. See below code with in code two approuches

```
<?php
class Inspection
{
    /**
     * @OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Surface", mappedBy="inspection")
     */
    protected $surfaces;
}

/**
 * @Entity
 * @InheritanceType("JOINED")
 * @DiscriminatorColumn(name="discr", type="string")
 * @DiscriminatorMap({"surface" = "Surface", "surface_leagage" = "SurfaceLeakage", ...})
 */
class Surface
{
    protected $inpection;
    protected $description;
}

class SurfaceLeakage extends Surface
{
    protected $leakageLevel;
}

// .. other child classes (SurfaceTension, SurfaceSlope, ...)

class InspectionType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        // ...

        $builder->add('surfaces', CollectionType::class, [
            'entry_type' => SurfaceType::class,
        ]);
    }
}

// Approach 1, where each child is added to the SurfaceType
// with this approach data should be mapped false
// This approach ensures that I only have to call SurfaceType once and all fields are loaded, but
// could not make this work with data from DB through CIT.
// Also this method does not allow me to add field description (from parent) to all childTypes
class SurfaceType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('leakage', SurfaceLeakageType::class, array('mapped' => false));
        $builder->add('tension', SurfaceTensionType::class, array('mapped' => false));
        //  ...
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Surface::class,
        ]);
    }
}

class SurfaceLeakageType extends AbstractType
{

}

// Approach 2, where each childFormType could extend SurfaceType, like below but how to call/create the
// form and handling the data.
// With this approuch i could parent fields to the child
class SurfaceLeakageType extends SurfaceType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('description', TextareaType::class); // field from parent or ...
        parent::buildForm($builder, $options);


        $builder->add('leakageLevel', IntegerType::class); // own field
        //  ...
    }
}
```

Then there is form [inherit_data](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/inherit_data_option.html)

```
// Approach 3, inherit data, now each child should add this as a field like below,
// but how the only thing I'm doing on InspectionType build Surfaces as collection so
// i think inherit data also doesn't work
class SurfaceType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder->add('description', TextareaType::class);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'inherit_data' => true,
        ]);
    }
}

class SurfaceLeakageType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        // inherit fields
        $builder->add('leakage', SurfaceType::class, [
            'data_class' => SurfaceLeakage::class,
        ]);

        $builder->add('leakageLevel', IntegerType::class); // own field
    }
}
```

Hope someone could help me out

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for polymorphic forms. Check this bundle https://github.com/infinite-networks/InfiniteFormBundle

Answer (score 0):

Another option is by calling the base-type buildForm-function:

```
class SurfaceType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder->add('description', TextareaType::class);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Surface::class,
        ]);
    }
}

class SurfaceLeakageType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
    * @var SurfaceType
    */
    private $surfaceType;

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $this->surfaceType->buildForm($builder, $options);

        $builder->add('leakageLevel', IntegerType::class); // own field
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => SurfaceLeakage::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```